# GMSMapView display whole world map?

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am adding my map view like

```
mapView_ = [[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:_viewMapContainer.bounds];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.frame = _viewMapContainer.bounds;
[_viewMapContainer addSubview: mapView_];
```

In my application this view is only for displaying the whole map of the world and some markers. I am unable to display the whole world in one view.Any help will be appreciable ,I don't want the user interactions on it

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this problem

```
- (void)focusMapToShowAllMarkers
{       
CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation = ((GMSMarker *)_markers.firstObject).position;
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:myLocation coordinate:myLocation];

for (GMSMarker *marker in _markers)
    bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:marker.position];

[_mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withPadding:15.0f]];
}
```

Please try this and share the response.

happy coding :)

Comment: Thak you for your reply.Above code is for showing all markers in visible area. Actually what i want is to display full world map in the view